# Fetching only 5 columns from 111 columns in pivot table in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot, pivot-table, multiple-columns

I have a pivot table with 111 headers or fields and i am trying to create a pivot table with 1 header as row field and 5 headers as value fields.

I am able to fetch 1 row field but for value fields i am able to fetch 1 field only and remaining 4 fields are not fetching.

Please note headers are in row 14.

I tried below code until now.

```
Sub Pivot()

Dim PSheet As Worksheet
Dim DSheet As Worksheet
Dim PCache As PivotCache
Dim PTable As PivotTable
Dim PRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

Set PSheet = Worksheets("PivotTable")
Set DSheet = Worksheets("Options")

LastRow = DSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = DSheet.Cells(14, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = DSheet.Cells(14, 1).Resize(LastRow, LastCol)


Set PCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create _
(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange). _
CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(2, 1), _
TableName:="PivotTable")


Set PTable = PCache.CreatePivotTable _
(TableDestination:=PSheet.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable")


With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Client")
.Orientation = xlRowField
.Position = 1
End With
     
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Final Base")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 1
.NumberFormat = "#,##0"
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Sum of Green")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 2
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Sum of Amber)")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 3
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").addPivotFields("Sum of Toll)")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 4
End With

With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").PivotFields("Sum of Red)")
.Orientation = xlDataField
.Function = xlSum
.Position = 5
End With

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").ShowTableStyleRowStripes = True
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable").TableStyle2 = "PivotStyleMedium9"

End Sub
```

Comment: In `DSheet`, are the column headers actually "Sum of ____"? When the pivottable is first created, those pivotfield names will be the same as what they are in the source. Use the original name to find them, then you can rename them to your preferred name. Since names can be changed, I suggest using numbers to find each pivotfield, instead of names. The number is its column position in the source data.

Comment: Ohh, got it... i removed the sum of from each name. it worked. Thank you, it worked now.